# OpenDJ password policy attribute that control user name does not include in the password

Tags: authentication, opendj, password-policy

My application authenticate users via OpenDJ server. Application does not allows add user name with some other combination as a password. For example if user name is test, OpenDj does not allows to change the password as 1test. Can some tell me what is the (password policy) attribute that that control this behavior?

or is it default password policy?

Comment: At least I would like to know reason OpenDJ does not allows to add password which contains characters with user name..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to figured out the attribute that cause for this issue. it is check-substrings attribute in the Attribute Value node under Password Validators in the configuration (cn=Attribute Value,cn=Password Validators,cn=config). Once we set this value to true, it checks whether full or portion of user name contains in the password and does not allows user to change password.

https://forgerock.org/opendj/doc/configref/attribute-value-password-validator.html